# Percentage sign in matplotlib on y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following pandas plot:

[image]

Is it possible to add `'%'` sign on the y axis not as a label but on the number. 
Such as it would show instead of `0.0` it would be `0.0%` and so on for all the numbers?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime 
end = datetime.date.today()
start = datetime.date(2020,1,1)

data = web.DataReader('fb', 'yahoo', start, end)
data['percent'] = data['Close'].pct_change()
data['percent'].plot()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Here is how you can use [`matplotlib.ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html):**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can now control the display format of the y-axis. I think it will be `0.0%`.

```
yvals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(["{:,.1%}".format(y) for y in yvals], fontsize=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *plt.gca()* instead of  using *ax*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1.0))
```